# Java Scheduled Task Across Multiple Executions

Tags: java, timer

I've recently set up a Minecraft server for my friends and myself and I thought it would be a fun project to program my own maintenance wrapper for it, in which I periodically reboot, backup, and diagnose various aspects of the server.

I saw the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) class and figured it would be perfect, but I ran into a problem.  I shut down my computer almost every night, and this class works on an elapsed time basis, and I would like to run some tasks only once a week.  What would be the simplest way to implement this?

Is there another class I could use that automatically handles executing tasks based on actual time instead of elapsed time that I could use instead?

EDIT: I should add that I realize straightforward use of any standard class won't work.  But it could easily be possible to save the next execution time to disk every time I execute a task and then recall the list when starting the wrapper back up the next time, allowing it to resume where it left off, more or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).

Quartz contains persistence mechanism out of the box, among other things, like a scheduling service should.

Comment: This seems perfect.  I would like to avoid using 3rd party libraries if possible, but I will definitely turn to this if I cannot create a solution myself!  I would +1 this if my account wasn't still new.

Comment: hmm. so you're looking for a 3rd party class, but no 3rd party library will do? I'm not sure the difference between a library and a class is that big...

Comment: No, I mean if there's a plausible way to implement it with native Java classes, that's the preferred method.  Otherwise, I might just use Quartz.

Comment: As far as I know, Quartz is implemented with standard Java classes. It is also open source so you can check that out.

Answer (score 1):

Using a scheduler library ([Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)) can perform these types of functions when coupled with a database back-end.  Jobs can be scheduled to run at particular times or frequency.